# Add external jar to web project class-path

Tags: java, web-applications, jar

I have a web application developed in JAVA and I have a jar file. I would like to add the jar file to the application class-path. I know a web application includes libraries from WEB-INF/lib/* but I want to include a jar under this location C:/myLib.jar. Is that possible, if it does how can I do it?

regards,
micuss

Comment: ....which web application container are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, jboss is a bit difficult on classloading, but its definitely possible.
you need to add a new jboss module for your external jar and then declare your web application to depend on that module.

there's a complete guide for this [here](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/HowToPutAnExternalFileInTheClasspath).

its possible to define a module to reference a jar file completely outside the jboss folder (c:\mylib.jar in your case) but it'll be easier on you if youre willing to move the jar into /modules

see [here](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/MODULES/Module+descriptors) for complete documentation on how to write module descriptors. you can set the path to lead to your external jar (but its gonna be ugly)